# IF in an SDL_PollEvent does not work as expected

Tags: c, if-statement, sdl-2

EDIT: I have solved the issue by changing `SDLKEYUP` to `SDLKEYDOWN`. Anyone could explain why?

I'm trying to code a pause button when pressing 'p' in C with SDL2.

The code below stops the sprite movements when pressing 'p' and resume it when pressing 'r':

```
SDL_PollEvent(&event);
switch(event.type)
{
    case SDL_QUIT:
        continuer = 0;
        break;
    case SDL_KEYUP:
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_p:
                    pause=1;
                    break;
            case SDLK_r:
                    pause=0;
                    break;
        }
}
```

But the code below does not pause when pressing 'p', int pause=0 declared at start and outside the main loop and not modified anywhere else than in the SDLK_p below. As if the `if(pause==0)` was not working:

```
SDL_PollEvent(&event);
switch(event.type)
{
    case SDL_QUIT:
        continuer = 0;
        break;
    case SDL_KEYUP:
        switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_p:
                if(pause==0)
                {
                    pause=1;
                    break;
                } else pause=0;
                break;
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                continuer=0;
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Add some logging in both the if and else portion of the code and see if it is getting hit and when.

Comment: Type? You say in `SDLK_r ` for second code but it's `SDLK_p`?

Comment: Yes my bad, SDLK_p

Comment: @RetiredNinja Do you mean adding breakpoints by logging?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Or do you mean something like a stderr and GetError()? To be honest I'm a beginner and never used one before, would you mind pointing me in the good direction to log that if and else statement please?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't check return value of `SDL_PollEvent` and as the result process stale data. It returns 0 if no event returned from even queue, meaning you should *not* process what is in your event structure, as `SDL_PollEvent` didn't fill it. What's happening here is you process old contens of your event structure (probably filled from previous poll, not enough code shown to be sure).

If you change it to KEYDOWN you still have the same problem of processing keydown multiple times, but when key is released your last event data is KEYUP, so your keydown reaction code isn't triggered anymore.

Furthermore, single graphics frame could easily have multiple events in it, so events needs to be processed in a loop:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    // process event contents
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! I understand now.